# SQL query answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL I am selecting the following:

```
SELECT itemid, custid, email FROM tableA;
```

I can have multiple `itemid` for each one `Custid` and only one email like

```
itemid1, custid, email
itemid2, custid, email
itemid3, custid, email
```

How can i send only one email per customer specified that he has 3 itemid?

thanks

Comment: Aare you wanting a "Count" or a "List" of items? If list, answer varies based on rdbms... so what flavor of SQL?? MSFT, MySQL, oracle, etc?

Comment: search online for `select distinct` which is another possibility

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to have email in the same table as itemid (not a normalized schema).  I'd normally (no pun intended) expect to see one table of email, custid and another of custid, itemid and perhaps another of itemid, itemname or whatever. That would be a normalized schema with custid, itemid as a junction table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(itemid), custid, email 
from tableA
group by email, custid
```

After clarification that the OP is joining tables and wants a list of items in one row with the email address, we have this query:

```
select b.custid, b.email, 
   itemids = STUFF((select ',' + itemid 
             from tableA a 
             where a.custid = b.custid FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
from tableB b
```

This will do it, but if you need more info about the items I would strongly recommend getting a list of customers and then looping through them to get the item info as you go.

Comment: Change that to `SELECT count(itemid), custid, email ...` and I think you'll have it.

Comment: lol... I copied, pasted, and added group by... Forgot to change the itemID part.  Thanks @JNevill!

Comment: Though I do feel like I just did someone's homework for them.  I'm going to pretend it's too late in the semester for such a simple question.

Comment: i know that but probably i did not explain very well. from that sql i have these items . .. for the same email (assume is 1 customer with 3 itemids) is it possible to write a new one sql that sends one email and describe that  the specific customer has 3 itemid , itemd1, itemd2, itemd3( i do not want to count them)

Comment: Please add more info to your question then.  What kind of database are you using?  What is the table structure?  Sample data?  Desired output example?  As you have described it, COUNT() and GROUP BY solves the problem.

Comment: db: sql server, i am using multiple tables ( using left join)  in order to get some fields from each one. the output is some of this

Comment: OK, then we would need to know the relevant fields from each of those tables

Comment: db: sql server, i am using multiple tables ( using left join)  in order to get some fields from each one. the output is some of this                       itemid1, custidA, emailA
itemid2, custidA, email A.  there is the same email (semailA) for the  customer (custid) and i want to send a db email . the problem as i described is that i only want to send ONLY ONE email for the customer to tell him that he has itemid1 and itemid2 . thanks

Comment: This is essentially the GROUP_CONCAT function in MySQL. Unfortunately sql-server has no similar aggregate function. There are work arounds though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server

Comment: Edited the answer to accommodate the list of items requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use function like this for all your `custid` and `email` :

```
ALTER        FUNCTION itemrow(@custid int, @email varchar(max)) --check your datatypes
RETURNS VARCHAR(max) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @itemrow VARCHAR(max)
  SELECT  @itemrow = COALESCE(@itemrow + ', ', '') + COALESCE(itemid,'')
  FROM tableA
  where email = @email
  and custid = @custid
return @itemrow
END
```